# Azure AD B2C for supporting multiple apps

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to use a single Azure AD B2C Tenant that supports multiple apps?

Say, I have the following apps:

- iOS Game app
- Some Facebook app
- My company website
- Android business app

Please keep in mind that it's possible and very probable that a user who's using the iOS game app will also use the Android business app.

There are two scenraios that I want to support:

1. **Global User** approach which I think is the easy and the out-of-the-box solution. In this case, even though the user is using multiple apps, he/she has a single user account in my Azure AD B2C tenant. This approach allows me to track user habits across multiple apps because I'm able to uniquely identify my user. For example, John Smith always appears with the same ID across multiple apps.
2. **App User** approach where John Smith would have two separate registrations in my Azure AD B2C i.e. one for the iOS game app registration and one for the Android business app registration. The key to this scenario is to be able to query my Azure AD B2C by AppId so that I can get only the iOS users or only the Android users or both.

Both scenarios have different business implications and I want to see if I'm able to handle both scenarios with a single Azure AD B2C tenant.

As I mentioned earlier, I think the first scenario is just standard behavior. The question I'm asking for the second scenario is being able to partition my Azure AD B2C tenant by AppId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user accounts in the directory are independent of how many applications you create. If you create multiple accounts in the directory for each user, then they will have to independently register for each application and remember passwords. Account changes (e.g. password reset, changing user properties, sign in email address etc.) will not be reflected across accounts. And like you said, you can query each user's habits regardless of the apps they use.

The best approach would be to have one account in the directory per user. For each client app (ios, android, web), provision an application in the directory that represents it. That will enable each application to have it's own redirect_uris, scopes etc.

Azure AD B2C does not track user's habits. So I assume you are going to use an external system for telemetry. That system can also store the application id as the data is sent to it, allowing you to mine user habits within a single application or across multiple applications. You can also gather data on how many users are using multiple apps, which app is preferred by users using multiple apps, are users with multiple apps more likely to use a particular IDP etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to focus on the second scenario where I want App User accounts. So the same user would have to register multiple times. First, can I use a single directory to have multiple accounts per user? The user may want to use the same email address or Google account. Would this be a problem? Would the directory allow the same email address or Google/Facebook/LinkedIn in multiple user accounts? If so, how will it differentiate which account the user is logging in under?

Comment: "If so, how will it differentiate which account the user is logging in under?" Precisely, that is the reason why the directory will only allow unique email addresses, google accounts, etc. Without knowing the scenario, it is difficult to suggest how to solve it. You may also want to reconsider whether you really need on directory, or multiple (one per app).